# properly handling "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I m using EF as ORM and on deleting a record I m getting below exception

```
"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Students_dbo.Classes_Class_ClassID". The conflict occurred in database "Demo.DataAccess.DemoContext", table "dbo.Students", column 'Class_ClassID'.
    The statement has been terminated."
```

I can understand it is because this record's PK is being refereed as  FK in other table's records. Question is how to properly handle it ? My code is handling `ConstrainException`  and `sQLException` but this error is not being caught by them rather it is being handled by `Exception`, Please see below code:

```
public void  DeleteClass(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            unitOfWork.ClassRepository.Delete(Id);
            unitOfWork.Save();
        }
        catch (ConstraintException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**Question:**
How to handle it specifically ? Exception handles every error but I need to know when expectly this "Constraint" exception fires. Based on exception type I will need to do different things.

Comment: Open up a Quick Watch window and run `e.GetType().Name`

Comment: @Malk thanks, it was DbUpdateException, I used it but I m thinking still this class can handle multiple exceptions that can accure while update. Please guide how spacifically I can know why this exception has accured. Please help.

Comment: @Malk, as different errors can accure while update. One of them will be Reference Constraint, to display message I need to catch or know exactly why this has happened. Please guide.

Comment: I took a quick look and it seems difficult to track down the MSDN reference page. I don't know enough about EF to help, but I would start by manually inspecting the exception and looking for flags I could use (like e.InnerException, e.HResult, e.Data, e.Message). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
```

cheers

Comment: it looks elegant solution but is it available with EF 5 ? I can find its assambly.

Comment: Yes It should work see the following link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationexception(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Hi hannsi have you sort-out the issue?